# Cocos2d Footstep Sounds

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

This is probably a simple question, however I have a problem trying to get a simple footstep sound to play every time my character makes contact with the ground:

Could someone kindly take a look at this:

```
// I want to play a sound when the walk is at frame 4
[[SimpleAudioEngine SharedEngine]playEffect:@"footstep.mp3"];
[pleaseplaymysoundatthisframe@"walk%04d.png"];
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: `This is probably a simple question` - Simple questions don't always have simple answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think, much more simplier will be to calculate needed delay, that will allow to play your sound in the needed moment.

Or you can divide your animation in two pieces and create sequence of actions. The first action will be CCAnimate with 0-4 frames of animation, than CCCallFunc action that will call method to play sound, then CCAnimate action with the rest of your frames.

Comment: Ok... thanks Morion, the first is not an option as the player will pause, jump etc. The timing must be only when that particular frame is touching the ground. I'll look into breaking up the animation although I though it would have been easier than this.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (mileage may vary, this is leaked from my frail memory):

```
// i suppose you have your animFrames in some local var animFrames
// and your CCSprite in some other local/iVar frameOne

float animationDuration=0.8f;
int animationFrames=12;
float fourthFrameTime=animationDuration*4/animationFrames;
float animFrameDelay=animationDuration/animationFrames;

id animateSprite=[CCAnimation animationWithFrames:animFrames delay:animFrameDelay];
id playFootsteps = [CCSequence actions:[CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:fourthFrameTime],
                                       [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self
                                                           selector:@selector(playFootSteps)],nil];
id spawn = [CCSpawn actions:animateSprite,playFootsteps,nil];
[frameOne runAction:spawn];


// and somewhere an 

-(void) playFootSteps{
    [[SimpleAudioEngine SharedEngine]playEffect:@"footstep.mp3"];
}
```

if this is a recurring theme in your app, i suggest you create a meta sound manager that can be invoked via a home-grown protocol/interface from any object instance (typically using a 'singleton', to stick with cocos2d's general approach), and that you manage the complexity of sound start/stop/resume in there.